# Calculating overtime using python

Tags: python

Hi I am python beginner!
Here is the questions I am having problem with!

Question:

Write a program to prompt the user for hours and rate per hour using raw_input to compute gross pay. Pay the hourly rate for the hours up to 40 and 1.5 times the hourly rate for all hours worked above 40 hours. Use 45 hours and a rate of 10.50 per hour to test the program (the pay should be 498.75). You should use `raw_input` to read a string and `float()` to convert the string to a number. Do not worry about error checking the user input - assume the user types numbers properly.

My answer was below but can't get 498.75, and I am not too sure where it went wrong. 
Please help :)

```
hrs = raw_input('Enter hours ')
h= float(hrs) #why use float?
rate = float(10.5)

if h <= 40:
    pay = h*rate
elif h > 40:
    pay = ((h-40)*rate*1.5)+rate*40   

print "Your pay is %d" %pay
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you print the pay of the user, you use `%d` to print the actual pay. To display floating point numbers (such as 498.75), you have to use `%f` (or more precisely, `%.2f` since you can't pay someone less than 1 cent).

So this would be the correct way, that wields 498.75 :

```
hrs = raw_input('Enter hours ')
h= float(hrs) #why use float?
rate = float(10.5)

if h <= 40:
    pay = h*rate
elif h > 40:
    pay = ((h-40)*rate*1.5)+rate*40   

print "Your pay is %.2f" %pay
```

You can find more informations regarding string formatting [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations)

Also, regarding the `h= float(hrs) #why use float?` :
by default, `raw_input()` returns a string, you have to use `float()` to parse this string to a floating point number, and to use it in your computation later on.

Hope it'll be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is correct, but you are using `%d` to print the value of variable `pay`, which converts it back to `int` and the decimal part is ignored.

So try using `%s` or `%f` or `%.2f`.

Answer (score 2):

Your calculation is correct, you just need to format the output correctly. `%d` is for integers so changing to `%f` which is used for floats will do the trick:

```
print "Your pay is %f" %pay
```

With above change you'll get following output:

```
Your pay is 498.750000
```

You can find the full list of different format specifiers from [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).